# String append with format in android

Tags: android, string

Anybody help me please. I don't know how to append the String with format in android similar to this:

```
String key = "";
append("%d-%d-%d", 0, 1, 2));
```

Please give me an example. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use StringBuilder or StringBuffer but with adequate initial capacity to avoid re-allocation. The default capacity is 16, so once you exceed that, the data has to be copied into a new bigger place. Use append not +.

```
int integer = 5;

StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(100);
 s.append("something");
 s.append(integer);
 s.append("more text");
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use either StringBuffer or StringBuilder

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String args[]) {
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Test");
  sb.append(" String Buffer");
  System.out.println(sb); 
}  
}
```

This produces following result:

```
Test String Buffer
```

StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder("foo");
strBuilder.append("bar");
strBuilder.append("baz");
String str = strBuilder.toString();
```

For format, try

```
String.format("Hello %1$s, your name is %1$s and the time is %2$t", name, time)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method to do that.

```
String test = "%d-%d-%d";
String.format(test, 0, 1, 2);
```

Or with the `Locale`.

```
String.format(Locale.US, test, 0, 1, 2);
```

Comment: I got a warning: Implicitly using the default locale is a common source of bugs: Use String.format(Locale, ...) instead